# Permission denied when setting values in sysctl on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: vps, ubuntu-12.04, kernel-panic, sysctl

I am trying to configure my Ubuntu 12.04 VPS (OpenVZ) to reboot when it runs out of memory. To do this I have added following lines to my "/etc/sysctl.conf" file.

```
vm.panic_on_oom = 1
kernel.panic = 14
```

But when I run the configuration using the command "sudo sysctl -p" I get following errors.

```
error: permission denied on key 'vm.panic_on_oom'
error: permission denied on key 'kernel.panic'
```

I have tried running the same command as root and found the same error.

Can anyone please point out what am I doing wrong? or how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenVZ doesn't allow access to kernel parameters from inside the container.

I think the newer versions of Openvz ( Kernel 2.6.32 + ) fix this issue, but without a kernel upgrade on your OpenVZ host, you're SOL.

Try submitting a support ticket to your VPS provider.